# Add a project to a Visual Studio solution, without the project going into Perforce

Tags: visual-studio, perforce

I know this is possible because one of my older solution files has a mix of some projects under source control and some not.

However I can't seem to reproduce that configuration with a newer solution. Every time I add a project to the solution it acquires a yellow cross and under **Pending Checkins** the project is listed as a **Newly added file**.

This is with the Perforce plugin for VS2008.

I have tried adding a brand new project, vs an existing project. I have tried **p4 obliterate**. I have tried disconnecting and reconnecting source control. Binding and unbinding.

After all this, every time I try and add the project it gets a pesky little yellow cross. I can't seem to tell Perforce and VS that, while I do want source control on the majority of the solution, *I don't want this one project file under source control*.

Comment: The solution file contains references to the projects you add. If the solution is under source control and the project is not how will this work for other people that get the source (but not the project)?

Comment: @klausbyskov - thanks - your comment helped me to rethink this. i've added my answer below. duh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see now that the way to have multiple projects under one solution, some projects under source control, and others not ... is to avoid having the solution itself under source control. That way I get just the projects I'm interested in checked in and out and the rest ignored.

Which, in fact, on closer inspection, is how I've managed (by muddle, mistake or design, I can't remember) to solve this in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Under File, Source Control, go into the Bindings dialog. Click the project in question and unbind it. You can leave the other projects, and the solution itself, bound to source control.

Comment: just tried it but the little yellow plus signs appear all over the new project